# Get the DML query on event of data change caused by the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to monitor some tables in order to capture any data changes (`insert`, `update`, `delete` queries).

I tried creating a trigger on these events, but unlike DDL trigger, I can't use `eventdata()`, which returns exact query that issued the trigger.

There are some workarounds, but non of them fully satisfied my needs. The most promising is:

```
use MyDatabase
go

CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON MyDatabase.dbo.TestTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  
AS
begin
    SELECT [text]
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
    WHERE session_id = @@SPID
end
```

But this always returns text of `create trigger` statement, not actual query.

I have read, that it should return the query - so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds more like you want to look into [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: dbcc inputbuffer(@@spid)

Comment: @TapakahUa It returns text of entire SQL document.

Comment: actual query = `SELECT [text] FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, one can use Extended Events and capture for example `sql_statement_completed` event to capture statements, that were successfully run on a server. There can be a filter (predicate) specified, to capture only `insert` statements, `update` statements, etc.

In case of such event, SQL stored event information (in XML format) in a target (which also has to be specified - can be a file). This information contains various data, **including SQL statement** which triggered the event.

Also, there can be specified additional info to include, such as **username**.

To capture edits to table through *Edit top 200 rows*, one need to capture also `rpc_completed` event.